# Why isn't this function running?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
  $('.posts li img').each(function() {
    if( this.complete )
      imageResize($(this), 64, 64);
    else
      $(this).load(imageResize($(this), 64, 64));
  });
```

I tried adding "alert('test')" to imageResize(), but it isn't working. Is there any reason why imageResize() isn't being called?

Comment: Does the DOM node have a `complete` attribute? Also, you want to use `{}` for the `if()` if you want more than one statement. Personally, I'd suggest avoiding use space-delimited control structures in Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it a function:

```
$(this).load(function(this) {imageResize(this, 64, 64)});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that this is the problem, but it's certainly a potential problem.  The second imageResize() call will be executed immediately and the return code used as the handler for the load event.  You need to wrap it in an anonymous function and use that instead, e.g.

```
  $('.posts li img').each(function() {
    if( this.complete )
      imageResize($(this), 64, 64);
    else
      $(this).load(function() {imageResize($(this), 64, 64);});
  });
```